# How can I ping a range of IP addresses simultaneously in an Android App

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello and thanks for looking.

I would like to be able to ping several IP addresses simultaneously from an android app. I've written the code below and want to be able to call my "Ping Something" method multiple times on different threads. If I do this as is at the moment the results all interfere with each other and basically the thread that runs last overwrites all the others. What is the best way to achieve the objective. I.e. being able to ping multiple IP addresses from an android app without having to wait for the previous result to finish.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Nat

This would be called from a timer or by pressing a button.......

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PingSomething("www.bbc.co.uk");
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PingSomething("someotherip");
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PingSomething("anotherip");
            }
        }).start();
```

This is the method that I've written simplified somewhat...

```
    public void PingSomething (String ahost) {
    String pingResult;
    Boolean noresponse, response;
    String inputLine;
    InetAddress theaddress;

    try {
        theaddress = InetAddress.getByName(ahost);
        ahost = theaddress.getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        ahost = "noip";
    }

    String pingCmd = "ping -c 1 -t 5000 -w 1 -W 1  " + ahost;

    try {

    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    inputLine = "";
    pingResult = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        pingResult = pingResult + (inputLine + "\n");
    }
    // Do something with pingResult
final String temppingresults = pingResult;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temppingresults, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
}
```

Comment: Your whole program seems rather strange. Normally when one talks about pinging an IP address one means using network I/O calls - opening a TCP/IP socket and performing socket-based calls to read and write data, and maybe also ping, but that is typically a by-product of trying to keep the connection alive. Instead, you're starting a process to perform a system command, which just happens to use network I/O. So I'm curious as to what your real objective is here.

Comment: Hello. I'm a bit of an noob so I might be going about this  completely the wrong way and happy to take any suggesttions. All I want to do is ping 1 - 100 IP addresses simultanisously to find out if they are on line or not. Think of it like an android version of the windows program freeping. I might want to ping my router, a couple of servers and an Internet address all at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: @RenniePet, he's talking about an ICMP Echo message, which the ping command sends.
Android doesn't allow apps to send ICMP messages on their own, only TCP/UDP over sockets, so he needs to execute the ping command instead.

Comment: What Daniel said. ;-)

Comment: @DanielKopitchinski: OK, thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: No worries and thanks for taking the time to look. I'm still not sure I have a solution for this so if anyone has any other suggestions please feel free to comment. Thanks again. Nat

Comment: Why do you think they are not executed simultaneously? I tried your code, adding some logging to the PingSomething method - the requests fail on my emulator, but they are executed at the same time.

Comment: Hello and thanks for looking. In the case of the code above they are executing simultaneously. The problem is that they interfere with each other. So for example say I ping www.google.co.uk and at the same time I ping "notarealhost" the results of the second thread overwrite the "pingrsults" variable of the first.

Comment: No, they don't overwrite each other, pingresults are local variables. Just store them in external Dictionary (HashMap).

Comment: Ah yes but it still doesn't work because I have been told that ICMP ping has no socket context and so, when several threads send pings and the gnips come in, the network stack cannot route the gnip to the originating thread. Say I add a toast to display ping result at the end of the PingSomething method.  If I just execute the first call of the ping something method it works fine. However if I call it twice as shown above the second result is displayed twice. I'm not really sure what is going on hence the question here but it definitely doesn't work. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce that. The pings are returned correctly and the toasts are shown correctly, tested that both on emulator and real device. Do you create toast using Handler?

Comment: Really appreciate you looking at this. Maybe its something I am doing wrong. I've added the code I am using with for the toast in above. Maybe the problem is there?

Comment: Or perhaps with the final variable? If so how do I pass the PingResult to a toast? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every thread is using identical variables.  So, thread 1/2/3 are running concurrently, but they're all writing to the same variables, so the thread that terminated last will ultimately be the last one to write to the variables.  You need to create new methods, one per thread.

For example, `PingSomething`, `PingSomething2` and `PingSomething3`, each having it's own methods and variables.  For example, `PingSomething2` would have the following variables:

```
String pingResult2;
Boolean noresponse2, response2;
String inputLine2;
InetAddress theaddress2;
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with that is that I may want to ping 3 hosts or maybe 100 hosts. The number may change dynamically. I don't really want to create 100 methods on the off chance I may want to ping 100 hosts so is there a better way of coding this to work dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: It would probably havebbeen better if I had used a for loop and an array in the code to submit the ping requests as this would have better illustrated what I am trying to achieve. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

for me  :  ping -c 1 -t 5000 -w 1 -W 1

gives a error about ttl out of range

try this too :

```
String[] commands = {"ping host1 &","ping host2 &" };

runAsRoot(commands);

public void runAsRoot(String[] cmds){
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

            for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                    os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
            }           

            os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
            os.flush();
            p.waitFor();
            Log.d("URL" ,"su commands success");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("URL" ,"su command failed");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d( "URL" ,"su command failed (waitfor failed)" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and read directly from pipe or  try to redirect output if you need output of the result of ping

ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo online || echo offline

and latter read that log or your choice

you can replace 'su' with 'sh' in p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") ,and you'l run withoout root. If you add the '&' ("ping host1 &") the pings wil go in background and all are running in same time ,so you have as many ping as you want running in bacgkround , and you can redirect each to a log file and read that log file from java code.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but two things spring out at me just looking at the code (and I am no means an experts so please correct me if I'm wrong). Firstly - it appears to require root access which I don;t have and don't want to gain. Secondly it still appears to be calling the ICMP requests sequentially in a for loop rather than calling multiple requests at the same time but I may be misunderstanding the code. Have I interpreted this correctly or am I off base here?

Comment: This solution does indeed require root.  You can achieve the same without using `su`.  Simply redirect output to `Log.d` and read.

Comment: you can replace 'su' with 'sh' in p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") ,and you'l run withoout root. If you add the '&' ("ping host1 &") the pings wil go in background and all are running in same time ,so you have as many ping as you want running in bacgkround , and you can redirect each to a log file and reed that log file from java code.